# Covariance with C++/CLI and Templates

Tags: c++, .net, templates, c++-cli, polymorphism

I'm trying to make a bridge between my native library and my C# client code.

To do this, I have an interface called "IHasManagedWrapper":

```
#ifndef IHASMANAGEDWRAPPER_H_
#define IHASMANAGEDWRAPPER_H_

template <typename T>
class IHasManagedWrapper
{
public:
    virtual T^ CreateManagedWrapper() = 0;
};

#endif
```

Then, to test polymorphism of the returned CLI types, I created two native classes, Parent, and Child, where Child inherits off of Parent:

Parent:

```
#ifndef PARENT_H_
#define PARENT_H_

#include "IHasManagedWrapper.h"

ref class CLIParent;

class Parent : public IHasManagedWrapper<CLIParent>
{
public:
    Parent();
    ~Parent();

    virtual char* GetName();

    virtual CLIParent^ CreateManagedWrapper();
};

#endif
```

Child:

```
#ifndef CHILD_H_
#define CHILD_H_

#include "Parent.h"
#include "IHasManagedWrapper.h"

ref class CLIChild;

class Child : public Parent, IHasManagedWrapper<CLIChild> // uh-oh...
{
public:
    char* GetName();

    CLIChild^ CreateManagedWrapper();
}; // error C2555: 'Child::CreateManagedWrapper': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'Parent::CreateManagedWrapper'


#endif
```

I got it to work by changing the "CLIChild" to "CLIParent" and removing the CLIChild's inheritance off of IHasManagedWrapper, but that means that each time I call Child->CreateManagedWrapper(), I get a CLIParent object which I then need to manually cast to a CLIChild object.

i.e.

```
CLIChild^ child = safe_cast<CLIChild^>(pChild->GetManagedWrapper()); // pChild->GetManagedWrapper() returns a CLIParent^ object
```

Though that isn't *too* bad, is there a way to make it so that CLIChild->CreateManagedWrapper() will return a CLIChild object, while preserving the IHasManagedWrapper interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue by diverting the body of the overloaded virtual method into a specific method, say `Child::CreateManagedWrapperChild`, and then call that specific method when you know you are dealing with a `Child`. The overloaded virtual method would simply call the specific method and upcast its result to `CLIParent` to match the correct method signature.

```
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    char* GetName();
    CLIParent^ CreateManagedWrapper() { return CreateManagedWrapperChild(); }
    CLIChild^ CreateManagedWrapperChild(); // actual code in this method
};
```

This doesn't look as clean as what you hoped to write, but it's accepted by the compiler and should work well in practice for only one level of inheritance. For more than one, you would have to make `CreateManagedWrapperChild` virtual too, overload it the same way in say `GrandChild`, and also overload the original virtual method to call directly the  `CreateManagedWrapperGrandChild` method, to avoid a nested virtual call.

However, for a large inheritance tree, this technique isn't very practical, because of the explosion of specific virtual methods.